# Automatically nest JSON objects based on duplicate parents

Tags: json

I've had to do something of a database migration for a work project, with the help of someone doing manual data entry. The data is a series of books, with each book containing multiple audio clips of narrated readings.

Previously, one book would have had multiple clips associated with it, but due to factors regarding the manual data entry, each clip is now associated with a separate copy of it's parent.

so instead of...

`harry potter {
  ..hp info
  harry potter 1 {
    ..hp1 info
  }
  harry potter 2 {
    ..hp2 info
  }
}`

we have

`harry potter {
  ..hp info
  harry potter 1 {
    ..hp1 info
  }
}`

`harry potter {
  ..hp info
  harry potter 2 {
    ..hp2 info
  }
}`

The data set is quite large, so I'm looking for any way to automatically consolidate all the clips together from a given book, so that the data looks more like the first example.

Comment: This is not a solve my homework for me site... just sayin

Comment: Actually, this is a work project I'm having trouble with, but thanks for your helpful input. Lets ignore the fact that's effectively what the site is for.